# How to add numbers to grouped columns that might repeat, in chronological order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query:

```
DECLARE @EmploymentLength TABLE
  (
   EmployeeID INT,
   Date DATE,
   DateFlag CHAR(1),
   RowNumber INT
  );

INSERT  INTO @EmploymentLength
        (
         EmployeeID,
         Date,
         DateFlag
        )
        SELECT  z.EmployeeID,
                z.Date,
                z.DateFlag
        FROM    (SELECT EmployeeId,
                        HireDate AS Date,
                        'H' AS DateFlag
                 FROM   dbo.Employment
                 WHERE  EmployeeId = 328195
                        AND HireDate IS NOT NULL
                 UNION
                 SELECT EmployeeId,
                        TerminationDate AS Date,
                        'T' AS DateFlag
                 FROM   dbo.Employment
                 WHERE  EmployeeId = 328195
                        AND TerminationDate IS NOT NULL) z;


SELECT  *
FROM    @EmploymentLength
ORDER BY Date;
```

Result:

[image]

I need this to end up like this:

[image]

After this is done, I can group by the RowNumber to get the MAX() and MIN() of each row number group (1, 2, 3...).

If the last 2 records were "T", then I'd have 2 4's and so on.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I need to group each DateFlag and add a number to each group but it has to be in order ... (by date).

So in this example, you have 2 records that fall into the first group (group 1).

Then one record for group 2 (T)

Then one record for group 3 (H)

Then one record for group 4 (T)

Comment: Why first two lines should get `RowNumber` = 1? I can't understand what you're asking for; can you rephrase it?

Comment: Reubens, I edited my post. Check it out at the end for a clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a difference of `row_number()` values to describe the group and then an additional `dense_rank()` to enumerate them.  I think the following works:

```
select el.*, dense_rank() over (partition by EmployeeId order by grp)
from (select el.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by date) - 
              row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, DateFlag order by date)
             ) as grp
      from @EmploymentLength el
     ) el;
```

There are situations where the `grp` value might actually repeat for different groups within an employee.  In that case, it is better to use the minimum date for each group for the enumeration:

```
select el.*, dense_rank() over (partition by EmployeeId, order by grpdate)
from (select el.*, min(date) over (partition by EmployeeId, DateFlag, grp) as grpdate
      from (select el.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId order by date) - 
                    row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, DateFlag order by date)
                   ) as grp
            from @EmploymentLength el
           ) el
     ) el
```